# Django tutorial, Getting: TypeError at /admin/ argument to reversed() must be a sequence

Tags: python, django-1.8

I'm working my way through the django tutorial for version 1.8 and I am getting an error that I am stuck on and can't seem to figure out. I thought I was following the tutorial pretty much to the T.

I have the following tree set up:

`.
├── dj_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
└── polls
    ├── admin.py
    ├── admin.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc`

and have, just as in the tutorial for **polls/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
}
```

and for my **dj_project/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')), 
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]
```

and in **polls/views.py** i have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("is there something here?")
```

so when I go to `<mysite>/polls` I see "is there something here", but if I go to `<mysite>/admin`, I get the error: `TypeError at /admin/ argument to reversed() must be a sequence`. If I remove polls from urlpatterns in `dj_project/urls.py`, the admin comes in fine.

What might be the problem? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are you trying to use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) anywhere?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the **polls/urls.py** file,
you are declaring the urlpatterns as dict, it must be a list.

change the

```
urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
}
```

to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Can it be a set? Or could you declare a set named urlpatterns, then change it to a list?

Comment: I'm not sure if you really want to convert the `urlpatterns` to `set` or just misunderstood the *it must be set as a list* part of my answer. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Like, if I were to want to have a url for every object in a database, would I be able to convert it to a set, to delete possible duplicates, then back into a list?

Comment: You can convert the `urlpatterns` to `set` to remove duplicates and change back to a `list`. But i see no significance doing it, because urlpatterns are generally written manually. Why would you create urls for each and very row/object in the db. why not use a simple regex?

Comment: Fun Fact: If you define a dict (which would be wrong) and process it with `format_suffix_patterns()` it will be okay - the function does not seem to mind and converts it properly. I went and copied a bit of code with dict and function for my new app, then removed format_suffix_patterns and the whole thing went boom.